# TYPO3 can't enable htmlArea RTE

Tags: content-management-system, typo3, wysiwyg, typo3-6.2.x

I try to install the module htmlArea RTE in TYPO3 6.2 (The LTS version).

In "Extension Manager", he's active, but in "Page", when I edit or create a new Text record, the WYSIWYG doesn't appear.

I'm on Firefox but I tried on other browser and he doesn't appear too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check in the module "User Settings" on tab "Edit & Advanced functions" if there is a checkmark at the option "Enable Rich Text Editor (if available)".

I tried a fresh installation and had the same problem. After set the checkmark there it worked.

Comment: A bug in the 6.2.0 version. The next update will contain a fix. This affects admins users only.