# htmlArea RTE not loading in TYPO3 6.2

Tags: content-management-system, typo3, wysiwyg, typo3-6.2.x

I have just migrated six websites from TYPO3 4.x to TYPO3 6.2 
In all of these, I use the htmlArea RTE, but only in one of these, the RTE does not work.

It's installed fine, but when I open a content element, the RTE keeps trying to load and simply does not open.

I know that there was a bug related to this ([TYPO3 can't enable htmlArea RTE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22839199/typo3-cant-enable-htmlarea-rte)) but this is NOT the solution for my problem.

Because all my other TYPO3 installations work fine, I am really clueless and would appreciate any help.

Comment: Please open the JavaScript console in your browser and look for errors related to RTE, then add them to this post. There can be a hundred reasons why the RTE is not loading...

Comment: Thank you, Lorenz.

The only error message that's showing in firebug is 
`"TypeError: this.tags[tagName].allowedClasses.trim is not a function
 
allowedClasses = this.tags[tagName].allowedClasses.trim().split(",");`


I must admit that I don't know much about JavaScript. Is this error message something like you were expecting to see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED! Just in case anyone else is having a similar problem:

In my PageTSConfig, I had this entry:
`RTE.default.buttons.blockstyle.tags.table.allowedClasses.classesTD`

But it needs to be this:
`RTE.default.buttons.blockstyle.tags.table.allowedClasses`

Now everything works perfectly